# Partially deleting buffer

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a program which is putting input audio into a `BufferedWaveProvider`. I would like to be able to delete the first x seconds of the buffer, in order to delete some of the audio in real time, before it is played.  I am able to clear the buffer completely, but if I only want some of the audio deleted, I cannot figure out how to get all the bytes out of the buffer, clear the buffer, and add some of the bytes back in.

I'm looking for a way to get the bytes or samples out of an array, so I can delete some of them, and then put the remaining bytes or samples back into array.

```
input.StopRecording();
output.Pause();

if (curdelay - output.DesiredLatency > dumpMs)
{
    //partially dump the buffer
}
else
{
    //completely dump the buffer
    buffer.ClearBuffer();
}
curdelay = (int)buffer.BufferedDuration.TotalMilliseconds;
```